# How to create a txt file with a list of directory names if directories have a certain file

Tags: bash

I have a parent directory with over 800+ directories, each of these has a unique name. Some of these directories house a sub-directory called `y` in which a file called `z`, (if it exists) can be found.

I need to script a loop that will check each of the 800+ for `z`, and if it's there, I need to append the name of the directory (the directory before `y`) into a text file. I'm not sure how to do this.

This is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in *; do
    if [ -d "y"]; then
        for f in *; do
            if [ -f "x"]
                echo $d >> IDlist.txt
            fi
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that any `foo/y/z` is a file (that is, you do not have directories with such names). If you had a really large number of such files, storing all paths in a bash variable could lead to memory issues, and would advocate for another solution, but about 800 paths is not large. So, something like this should be OK:

```sh
declare -a names=(*/y/z)
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]%%/*}" > IDlist.txt
```

Explanation: the paths of all `z` files are first stored in array `names`, thanks to a glob pattern: `*/y/z`. Then, a pattern substitution is applied to each array element to suppress the `/y/z` part: `"${names[@]%%/*}"`. The result is printed, one name per line: `printf '%s\n'`.

If you also had directories named `z`, or if you had millions of files, `find` could be used, instead, with a bit of `awk` to retain only the leading directory name:

```sh
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -path './*/y/z' -type f |
  awk -F/ '{print $2}' > IDlist.txt
```

If you prefer `sed` for the post-processing:

```sh
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -path './*/y/z' -type f |
  sed 's|^\./\(.*\)/y/z|\1|' > IDlist.txt
```

These two are probably also more efficient (faster).

Note: your initial attempt could also work, even if using bash loops is far less efficient, but it needs several changes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d/y" ]; then
        for f in "$d"/y/*; do
            if [ "$f" = "$d/y/z" ]; then
                printf '%s\n' "$d" >> IDlist.txt
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

As noted by @LéaGris, `printf` is better than `echo` because if `d` is the `-e` string, for instance, `echo "$d"` interprets it as an option of the `echo` command and does not print it.

But a simpler and more efficient version (even if not as efficient as the first proposal or the `find`-based ones) would be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for d in *; do
    if [ -f "$d/y/z" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$d" 
    fi
done > IDlist.txt
```

As you can see there is another improvement (also suggested by @LéaGris), which consists in redirecting the output of the entire loop to the `IDlist.txt` file. This will open and close the file only once, instead of once per iteration.

Comment: I bit cleaner `for d in */; do [ -f "$d/y/z" ] && printf '%s\n' "$d"; done > IDlist.txt`. Iterating over `*/` ensure to iterate only directories. Using `printf` rather than `echo` will prevent issues with directories names starting with a dash. Moving the redirection outside the loop prevents opening, writing and closing the file at each iteration but only once for the whole loop.

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks. As the `echo` issue is a real one that would impact the output, I will integrate your suggestion to use `printf`. For the rest you're (almost) right but I wanted to apply minimal changes to the OP, for easier understanding. And almost only because `for d in */` will keep the trailing slash in the output. I suspect that this is not the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to do some filtering using `find`

Below will list all z files recursively within current directory

Then let's say the one of the output was

```
./dir001/y/z
```

Then you can extract required part using multiple ways `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc

e.g. with grep

```
find . -type f | grep z | grep -E -o "y.*$"
```

will give

```
y/z
```

Comment: `find . | grep z` is an underutilization of the power of `find`. `find . -type f -name z` would do the same, plus selecting only files (yours selects also any directory named `z`), and only files which **full name** is `z` (yours selects also `baz`).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Agree it's not the most optimized command. Just provided answer based on my knowledge top of the head. Not at prompt hence couldn't verify optimized commands.

Comment: This will fail if `z` is a directory, not a file. You may need to test if it's a file or not.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```
for f in */y/z; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo ${f%%/*}
done
```

Note:
If there is a possibility of weird top level directory name like "-e", use `printf` instead of `echo`, as in the comment below.

Comment: Nice. Do not forget to double-quote `$f` in the test, just in case some names contain spaces. Last but not least, as noted by @LéaGris, `printf '%s\n' "${f%%/*}"` is better than `echo "${f%%/*}"` because the latter would fail on a directory name like `-e`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
shopt -s nullglob
outfile=IDlist.txt
>$outfile
for found in */y/x
do
  [[ -f $found ]] && echo "${found%%/*}" >>$outfile # Drop the /y/x part
done
```

The *nullglob* ensures that the loop is skipped if there is no match, and the quotes in the `echo` ensure that the directory name is output correctly even if it contains two successive spaces.

Comment: This will fail if `z` is a directory, not a file. You may need to test if it's a file or not.

Comment: Right. I wonder what the OP wants to see, if some `z` in the tree are files and other `z` are directories, but I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first example doesn't check that `z` is a file, but I think it's worth showing `compgen`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

compgen -G '*/y/z' | sed 's|/.*||' > IDlist.txt
```

---

Doing glob expansion, file check and path splitting with `perl` only:

```sh
perl -E 'foreach $p (glob "*/y/z") {say substr($p, 0, index($p, "/")) if -f $p}' > IDlist.txt
```